# How to stop resubmitting of page on refreshing the page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am using php as server side scripting and using a form for inserting data in database using MySql.On submitting the page it redirects to another page and shows thanks etc.But when user clicks refresh button then the form is submiting again, so please tell me how to stop this.

My code for first page is below-

```
<?php

$route=$_POST['route'];
$datee=$_POST['SelectedDate'];
$pick_time=$_POST['pick_time'];
$ampm=$_POST['ampm'];
$destination=$_POST['destination'];
$cab=$_POST['cab'];
$days="/";


?>

<html>
<head>



</head>
<body>
<form onSubmit="validateForm();" action="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=452"             method="post" name="localhire_select" >
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="outer" name="outer" align="left" style="width:300px;height:300px;background-        color:#FAFA23;border:1px solid;padding:10px 30px;">
<table width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td  widtn="60%" align="left">Pick-up Date:</td><td><input type="text" name="datee"     size="10px"  value=<?php echo $datee ; ?> /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="60%" align="left">Pick-up Time :</td><td><input type="text" name="time" size="10px"  value=<?php echo $pick_time."".$ampm; ?> /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="60%" align="left">Destination :</td><td><input type="text" name="destination" size="10px"  value=<?php echo $destination; ?> /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="60%" align="left">No. of Days :</td><td><input type="text" name="days" size="10px"  value=<?php echo $days; ?> /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="60%" align="left">Type of Cab :</td><td><input type="text" name="cab" size="10px"  value=<?php echo $cab; ?> /></td>
</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
<table width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td height="71" valign="middle" align="center"><input name="changeDetails" type="image" id="button" value="Submit" src="change.jpg"></td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

</td>
<td>
<div id="right" name="right" align="right" style="width:440px;height:300px;background-color:#F7EA2A;border:1px solid;padding:10px 30px;">

<table>
<tr style="background-color:orange;border:1px solid black;" height="30">
<td><b>Gurgaon-><?php echo $destination; ?> ->Gurgaon </b></td><td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr  height="20">
<td><input type="hidden" name="route" value="<?php echo $route; ?>"  />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Your Full Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="full_name" value="" size="20px"     /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address :</td><td><input type="textarea" name="address" value="" size="20px 20px"     /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile no. :</td><td><input type="text" name="mobile_number" value="" size="20px" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Pick-up Location :</td><td><input type="text" name="pickup_location" value="" size="20px" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<table>
<tr align="center">
<td height="71" align="center" valign="middle">
            <input name="localhire_select" type="image" id="button" value="Submit" src="book_cab.jpg"></td>


</tr>
</table>           

 </tr>

</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table></form>
</body>
<html>
```

`

And code for second page is-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$host="localhost";
$user_name="usr";
$pwd="pwd";
$database_name="db"; //assuming you created this
mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $pwd);
if (mysql_error()>"") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
mysql_select_db($database_name);
if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";

$datee=$_POST['datee'];
$time=$_POST['time'];
$destination=$_POST['destination'];
$days=$_POST['days'];
$cab=$_POST['cab'];
$route=$_POST['route'];
$full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$mobile_number=$_POST['mobile_number'];
$pickup_location=$_POST['pickup_location'];

 $query2="SELECT `order_number` FROM `count` WHERE 1";
 $count=mysql_query($query2);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($count))
{
   $variable = $row["order_number"];
}


$query3="UPDATE `count` SET order_number=order_number+1 WHERE 1";
mysql_query($query3);


$query1="INSERT INTO `booking`         (`pickup_date`,`pickup_time`,`destination`,`days`,`type`,`full_name`,`address`,`mobile`,`pi    ckup_location`,`route`,`order_number`) VALUES     ('$datee','$time','$destination','$days','$cab','$full_name','$address','$mobile_number','$    pickup_location','$route','$variable')";
mysql_query($query1);

mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a pattern called [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Essentially, after the form is posted, do all of your MySQL information and then *redirect* using below:

```
header('Location: thanks.php', true 303);
```

using a GET request.  Then, the user cannot refresh that page; it will only display the "Thanks."

Comment: Don't forget the `Location:`. I.e., `header('Location: thanks.php')`.

Comment: I didn't get it..pls explain more.

Comment: The `header` should be done after the form has completed its processing

Answer (score 0):

u need to use this SUBMIT button as POST in PHP.
TRY THIS!!!!

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$date=$_POST["date"];

Then use HEADER after INSERT QUERY.
LIKE this

echo header("location:thank.php");